# Ignore the Update iOS Badge option

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

We have implemented the MarketingCloudSDK version 5.2.1 in our iOS application. Everything works fine but there are some tweaks that we would like to do, but we are not sure how to achieve what we want.

The situation looks like this: we have some local notifications in the app that change the application icon badge number. Now, every time a push notification is sent from the Marketing Cloud with the `Update iOS Badge` setting set to `Yes`, this sets the badge number to `1`. This is undesired and we would like to disable this on the SDK level, so the badge number is not affected regardless of the state of this setting when sending the push notification. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible - the switch enables the APNS badge value on the push message to be sent to the device for setting by iOS itself (upon push receipt).

If the badging is not desired, the switch should be turned off in the message creation.